# NodeJS Web Service with Microsoft IIS

Tags: node.js, web-services, iis, web

I have a huge problem with my Web Service made in NodeJS and IIS. I have made a Web Service in NodeJS Express which is running fine on my localhost. I'm starting it by cmd -> and 'npm start' command and I have access to it via my localhost website which is using it. The problem is, I want to make it run via IIS. I have no idea how am I suppose to make it work, to open cmd and run command by the browser. I've searched for IISNode, but I can't figure it out how it suppose to work with Web Service, which is running by command line. I provided a screenshot to make it more clear. I will be really glad if someone can help me, how I can run my Web Service on IIS.

P.S. Only what I managed is to open my port on physical server, run my Web Service by command line and give an url to my website. But this is not what I want to achieve, I need to make it via IIS and how to get URL to web service to run it on my website.

[Web service running on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY9gy.jpg)

Comment: perhaps [this blog post](https://adamtuttle.codes/add-node-to-existing-iis-server/) might be of help

Comment: Well, that was too hard for me. I decided to make a C# Web Api to take care of my application. :) Thx for answer!